# Google Sheets Line Height issue after form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-macro

I need my row height in google sheets to stay at 40.
[image]
The issue I am having is every time a user submits a form and a new entry is created, the line height goes back to the original formatting.
[image] I creating a macro and thought there may be a way to run it through conditional formatting but I do not see any other option where I can dynamically run the macro.

I linked a video describing the issue I am having and why I need to have the line height to be consistent.
https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/006rfY-aq5Y_ERggwTG-q2XrA#lineheight

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need my row height in google sheets to stay at 40. The issue I am having is every time a user submits a form and a new entry is created, the line height goes back to the original formatting. Hope this helps. I also linked the visual for extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do it with a script, as guided in [Google Apps Script: Make Row Taller on Form Submit](https://alicekeeler.com/2017/10/01/google-apps-script-make-row-taller-form-submit/)

Basically, in the Spreadsheet you're going to go to **Extensions** > **Apps Script**. And in the the code box paste the foollowing code:

```
function makeTaller() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var last = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.setRowHeight(last, 40);
}
```

And click on Save Project:
[image]
Once it's saved you go to **Triggers**, click on **Add Trigger**, set **Select event source**: ***From Spreadsheet*** and **Select event type**: ***On form Submit***, then save it:
[image]
It will ask you for authorization (basically you are authorizing this script - you just created - access to the sheet), you might need to click Advanced and then allow.

Once this is done, the sheet rows will be resized to **40** on each form submit:
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @johnmoore If you think this is the best solution to your problem, then you should consider accepting it - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)